# Execution failed for task ':geocoding_android:processDebugManifest'

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to run a flutter project and it is not running. I did not change anythin on the code, I have this error:

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':geocoding_android:processDebugManifest'.

> Error while evaluating property 'packageOverride' of task ':geocoding_android:processDebugManifest'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':geocoding_android:processDebugManifest' property 'packageOverride'.
> > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
> > Package Name not found in C:\Users\dilek\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\geocoding_android-2.1.2\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

I tried to add package name to the mentioned file. Here is the content of the file:
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> </manifest>`

Comment: same here , any fix for that please ?

Comment: its works for me plz update the manifest for that plugin like this<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.baseflow.geocoding">
</manifest>

Comment: I changed the version of flutter and android studio as the same as the project, then it was solved.